# How to install python plugins using pip in azure web sites?

Tags: python, azure, flask, installation, pip

I've tried to deploy my web service into microsoft azure.

First I added my website from gallery.

Web sites -> New -> From Gallery -> Flask

And then Azure generated a simple website.

Later I deployed my source to azure website and tending a web.config file.

Then I got a error message like below.

Anyone know how to install python plugins using pip in azure web sites?

Regards,

---

```
Error while importing WSGI_HANDLER:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 469, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = getattr(__import__(module, fromlist=[callable]), callable)
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
   from application import frontend, api_v1
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\frontend\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
ImportError: No module named flask_debugtoolbar


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Comment: Are the required python packages listed in a requirements.txt file?